# Scala system processes don't die after application dead

Tags: java, scala, jvm, system-calls

I have an application in Scala that does system calls to ffmpeg. Sometimes the ffmpeg hangs forever. 
I am running this App in Mac OS X Eclipse. When I kill the java application while the ffmpeg command is running, the ffmpeg process does not get killed. Why?

```
import scala.sys.process.ProcessLogger
import scala.sys.process.stringSeqToProcess
import scala.sys.process.stringToProcess

object BugStreaming {
  def callFfmpeg(): (Int, String, String) = {
    val err = new StringBuilder
    val out = new StringBuilder

    val commandOutputs = ProcessLogger(
      (o: String) => out.append(o + "\n"),
      (e: String) => err.append(e + "\n"))

    println(s"ffmpeg saving...")

    val status = Seq("ffmpeg", "-i", "rtmp://200.136.27.12/live/tv", "-t", "5", "-y", "/tmp/x.wav") ! commandOutputs

    (status, out.toString, err.toString)
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val (s, out, err) = callFfmpeg()
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The process run on a separated OS process. Stopping the creator process (the jvm) does not kill the child one.
Also running the process with '!' make the caller thread to wait for the response.
If you will call the 'run' function instead of the '!' it will return the process which allow to be stopped.

```scala
val p = Seq("ffmpeg", "-i", "rtmp://200.136.27.12/live/tv", "-t", "5", "-y", "/tmp/x.wav").run(commandOutputs)
val f = Future { p.exitValue }
```

The run function return a process which has two functions `exitValue(): Int` and `destroy(): Unit`. The exitValue return the process exit value (same as the '!' does) and for that it need to be blocking (which mean the calling thread wait for the process to be complete). The destroy function kill the process.
You can now do:

```scala
f.map{_ match {
  case 0 => //status ok
  case _ => //handling errors...
}}
```

and if you need to kill it:

```scala
p.destroy()
```

Comment: Is there any way to kill the child processes when killing the father?

Comment: @DanielCukier This is related to the OS so I dont think so.  but you can use jvm shutdown hook for that: `sys.addShutdownHook{println("Bye Hook!"); p.destroy()}
` This will kill the process when the jvm is going down.